# Sitecore Layout details form modification

Tags: sitecore

On sitecore **Layout Details dialog** form, I want to show data source name along with rendering name.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: To answer your question the LayoutDetails is located here...\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\LayoutDetails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is applicable by overriding some Sitecore XML controls, and using the following code:

```
private void RenderRenderings(DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition, int selectedIndex, int index)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(deviceDefinition, "deviceDefinition");
        ArrayList renderings = deviceDefinition.Renderings;
        if (renderings == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition in renderings)
        {
            if (renderingDefinition.ItemID != null)
            {
                Item item = Client.ContentDatabase.GetItem(renderingDefinition.ItemID);
                XmlControl xmlControl = Resource.GetWebControl("DeviceRendering") as XmlControl;
                Assert.IsNotNull(xmlControl, typeof(XmlControl));
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                htmlGenericControl.Style.Add("padding", "0");
                htmlGenericControl.Style.Add("margin", "0");
                htmlGenericControl.Style.Add("border", "0");
                htmlGenericControl.Style.Add("position", "relative");
                htmlGenericControl.Controls.Add(xmlControl);
                string uniqueID = Control.GetUniqueID("R");
                this.Renderings.Controls.Add(htmlGenericControl);
                htmlGenericControl.ID = Control.GetUniqueID("C");
                xmlControl["Click"] = "OnRenderingClick(\"" + index + "\")";
                xmlControl["DblClick"] = "device:edit";
                if (index == selectedIndex)
                {
                    xmlControl["Background"] = "#D0EBF6";
                }
                this.Controls.Add(uniqueID);

                //Get DataSource item path
                var datasource = string.Empty;
                Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(renderingDefinition.Datasource))
                {
                    var dsItem = master.GetItem(renderingDefinition.Datasource);
                    if (dsItem != null)
                        datasource = dsItem.Paths.Path;
                }

                if (item != null)
                {
                    xmlControl["ID"] = uniqueID;
                    xmlControl["Icon"] = item.Appearance.Icon;
                    xmlControl["Header"] = item.DisplayName;
                    xmlControl["Placeholder"] = WebUtil.SafeEncode(renderingDefinition.Placeholder);
                    xmlControl["DataSource"] = datasource;
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlControl["ID"] = uniqueID;
                    xmlControl["Icon"] = "Applications/24x24/forbidden.png";
                    xmlControl["Header"] = "Unknown rendering";
                    xmlControl["Placeholder"] = string.Empty;
                    xmlControl["DataSource"] = string.Empty;
                }
                if (renderingDefinition.Rules != null && !renderingDefinition.Rules.IsEmpty)
                {
                    int num = renderingDefinition.Rules.Elements("rule").Count<XElement>();
                    if (num > 1)
                    {
                        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("span");
                        if (num > 9)
                        {
                            htmlGenericControl2.Attributes["class"] = "scConditionContainer scLongConditionContainer";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            htmlGenericControl2.Attributes["class"] = "scConditionContainer";
                        }
                        htmlGenericControl2.InnerText = num.ToString();
                        htmlGenericControl.Controls.Add(htmlGenericControl2);
                    }
                }
                RenderDeviceEditorRenderingPipeline.Run(renderingDefinition, xmlControl, htmlGenericControl);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Next step is to updated the following files:
\Website\sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Layouts\DeviceEditor.xml
\Website\sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Layouts\DeviceRendering.xml

You can find the source code in the following blog post:

http://baraamasri.blogspot.com/2017/03/custom-device-editor_21.html

Also, you can download a marketplace module that does this:
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/C/Custom_Device_Editor.aspx

Comment: Sure thing, will do.

Comment: @Adriaan I updated the answer, hope this is better.

Comment: @Mohammad Can you please suggest which class andxml file I need to modify to implement same functionality on Layout Details dialog which opens before Device editor Dialog. It will be very helpful for me

Comment: In the provided link for the blog post there are two screenshots for the two files you need to update, also the specific update is highlighted

Comment: Actually the page I am talking about is different from Device Editor.The required page is : click on Presentation Tab=>click Details =>"Layout Details" dialog opens.  Now I want to implement above functionality on this "Layout Details" dialog. Please help .